# Receiving items with query and keys range

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, batch-fetching

here's simple structure:

```
$countryCode
 -autoid13
  -category: vehicles
 -autoid12
  -category: sport
 -autoid11
  -category: food
 -autoid10
  -category: sport
 -autoid9
  -category: vehicles
 -autoid8
  -category: food
 -autoid7
  -category: sport
 -autoid6
  -category: sport
```

my question is how can i fetch only items with category: sport between items with id7-id11 ? /autoid keys are managed by firebase

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it

```
countryCode
 -autoid13
  -category: vehicles_13
 -autoid12
  -category: sport_12
 -autoid11
  -category: food_11
 -autoid10
  -category: sport_10
 -autoid9
  -category: vehicles_09
 -autoid8
  -category: food_08
 -autoid7
  -category: sport_07
 -autoid6
  -category: sport_06
```

and pseudo-code

```
   ref.orderBy("category")
      .queryStartingAtValue("sport_07")
      .queryEndingAtValue("sport_11")
```

will return

```
 -autoid7
  -category: sport_07
 -autoid10
  -category: sport_10
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i just tried couple solutions and i think a better one would be quering keys id7-11 on server side and then do filtering by category on client side, i'm fetching items 10 at once so it goes pretty nice, besides i need category text without subscript

Comment: @kam.voick You can keep a another child node for the actual text. What I posted is a typical design pattern in Firebase to query by two parameters. Glad you had another solution.